# Website works with 'www' but not without it

Tags: https, dns, ssl-certificate, web-hosting, google-cloud-load-balancer

I've recently set up a website on Google Cloud Platform using a Load Balancer. The website works perfectly fine when accessed with the 'www' prefix (e.g., [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)), but it returns an error when accessed without it (e.g., example.com).

My custom domain set-up
[image: Custom domain]

My certificate details
[image: certificate details]

What is the mistake that I am doing?